# Wrapper to Zend_Db is failing

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

All,

I wrote the following wrapper that extends Zend_Db class to provide db connectivity to my entire application. The db connectivity works fine, but it fails to execute queries when invoked from a different class.

```
class Testapp_DB extends Zend_Db {

        //Declare member variables.
        public $db          = null;
        public $db_host     = "";
        public $db_database = "";
        public $db_username = "";
        public $db_password = "";


 public function __construct()
        {

            //Read Database Info from Config File
            $this->db_host      = Testapp_Registry::get('config')->db->mysql->host;
            $this->db_database  = Testapp_Registry::get('config')->db->mysql->dbname;
            $this->db_username  = Testapp_Registry::get('config')->db->mysql->username;
            $this->db_password  = Testapp_Registry::get('config')->db->mysql->password;

            $db = Zend_Db::factory('Mysqli', array(
                'host'     => $this->db_host,
                'username' => $this->db_username,
                'password' => $this->db_password,
                'dbname'   => $this->db_database
            ));

            $db->getConnection(); //Works fine
            $this->db = $db;
 }
}
```

Trying to execute query in a PHP file that includes Testapp_DB - fails..

```
<?php

 $db = new Testapp_DB();
 print_r($db);  //I can see the DB object here
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_Log';
 $result = $db->fetchAll($sql, 2); //This method fails.. Don't know why. Any ideas?
 print_r($result);
?>
```

Can someone please explain, why the fetchAll method fails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Zend_Db* doesnt have any method other than *factory()*.

I dont really get, what you are trying to solve this way, but as far as I can see you need to call *query()* this way

```
$db->db->query();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works just fine.. How can I modify Testapp_DB class such that i can access $db->query() instead of $db->db->query()? Can I add a singleton pattern to it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using your wrapper, try this:

```
// Note: change your config to have a 'params' entry
$db = Zend_Db::factory(Testapp_Registry::get('config')->db->mysql);
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
Zend_Registry::set('database', $db);

// in your config
...mysql.params.host = ...
...mysql.params.dbname = ...
...mysql.params.username = ...
...mysql.params.password = ...
```

Then, your `Zend_Db_Table` objects will have connectivity, and in addition you can grab the connection using `Zend_Registry::get('database')`.  And, you'll make only one database connection once per request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a SQL file like schema.mysql.sql,
then test it on phpMyAdmin and when it's free of bugs run this code:

```
$bootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();
$bootstrap->bootstrap(‘db’);
$config = $bootstrap->getResource(‘db’)->getConfig();
$runCommand = “mysql -h “.$config["host"].” -P “.$config["port"].” -u’”.$config["username"].”‘ -p’”.$config["password"].”‘ “.$config["dbname"].” < “.dirname(__FILE__) . ‘/schema.mysql.sql’;
echo $runCommand;
system($runCommand);
```

Hope this helps! http://www.unexpectedit.com/zend-php/zend-db-exec-a-sql-file